# How to generate random variable X over [2,5] using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, random, histogram, uniform-distribution

I have to create a random variable *X* distributed uniformly over [2,5] and generate more than 10000 samples.

Then I have to estimate the probability density function of X using `histc()` or `hist()` functions, and plot estimated PDF with theoretic curve.

I have no idea how to solve it with MATLAB.

Comment: try rand(10000)*3+2 PDF is a flat line for uniform distribution

Answer (score 4):

Here are links to useful functions and resources:

- [RAND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) : Look up the first example for getting random numbers between two arbitrary limits. You can specify the number of random samples you desire in the function itself.
- The normalized [HISTC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) should give you a probability distribution function.
- If you have the statistics toolbox, you can do [MLE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mle.html) to get the best fit uniform distribution.

Happy data fitting!

Answer (score 1):

Generate the Uniform random variable using [`rand()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) for the [0,1] interval. Then shift it with `a` and scale (stretch) it with `b-a`.

```
N = 10000;
a = 2;      % lower bound
b = 5;      % upper bound
X = a + (b-a)*rand(N,1);    % X ~ Uniform(a,b)
```

Then plot the sample distribution & the theoretical distribution ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous))).

```
figure, hold on, box on
histogram(X,'normalization','pdf','DisplayName','Sample')
xRng = 2:.1:5;
plot(xRng,(1/(b-a))*ones(size(xRng)),'r--','LineWidth',2.8,...
    'DisplayName','Theoretical')
legend('show','Location','north','Orientation','horizontal')
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Probability Density')
```

[image: Uniform Distribution]